# Custom object CRUD permission still insufficient privilege

Tags: custom-object, configuration, object

I have a custom object with CRUD permission. Still it gets insufficient privilege. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Having Create,Read,Update and Delete permissions of an object allows you to - wait for it -- Create,Read,Update and Delete the records of that object. This is the permission at the object level.

Now you need to have record level access to do those to individual records. If you create a record under that object, you become its default owner and you are entitled to Create,Read,Update and Delete that record.

For reading and updating the records owner by other users you need to have explicit visibility for them depending on the Org Wide Defaults. If the OWD is:

1. Public read write - then now you can read/edit the records of other users too. You cannot delete the records of other users unless you have 'Modify All' for that object or 'Modify All Data' at the profile level.
2. Public Read - you will be able to read all the records under the object. But edit permissions need to be given explicitly
3. Private - in this case, you wont be able to see the records of other users unless it is shared with you.

In case yoy are facing difficulty in creating an object record itself, even though you have the create permission -> take a look at if you are able to at least read any parent records involved while saving.

Hope this helps